# iText RUPS fails to open PDF created with PDFreactor

Tags: pdf, itext

I have created a PDF from a webpage, using PDFreactor 6.3.6828 on Windows 7.  I would like to use iText RUPS 5.4.4 to view the resulting PDF structure, but RUPS gives a lot of errors when I try to load the PDF.  Any idea what is going wrong?  The PDF I am using is here:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/m0u6vtu09mn101k/Rainy%20Day%20Fun%20With%20Your%20Kids.pdf

Thanks!

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the `StructTreeRoot`. I'll put it on my TODO list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've done some investigations and I've found the problem. RUPS assumes that each element in the structure tree has an `/S` key. This key is mandatory in case of a ´StructElem´ dictionary, but in case of an object reference (`OBJR`), you may encounter dictionaries without a type and without an `/S` entry (at least: the PDF you shared contains such a dictionary). If adapted RUPS so that the `NullPointerException` is avoided. See http://sourceforge.net/p/itextrups/code/77/

You can build RUPS from the source code on SourceForge, or you can wait until the next release (scheduled for the end of November).

Comment: Forgot it was a java app... I guess this .NET guy will wait until the end of November!

Comment: Remind me over the weekend, and I may build you an exe on Saturday.

Comment: OK, I've found some time and I've built a SNAPSHOT version: http://itextpdf.org/documents/Rups.exe